# Manga where a guy used a red scarf that when activated used a sort of roulette wheel to determine its form

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for manga I read but have lost touch with. It was about this guy who used a red scarf that when activated used a sort of roulette wheel to determine its form (e.g., it could be a sword). He used it in a game that he used his phone to enter.

In the first couple of chapters the guy finds out his grandfather made a game and had died but before he died he set up a trial for him to protect a tomb from the tomb raider who after raiding a tomb gets the master of the tomb as a weapon.

Comment: This manga is know as te silver gaurdian as well as Yin Zhi Shoumuren

Answer (score 9):

This is [***The Silver Guardian (銀之守墓人, 銀の墓守り)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silver_Guardian), a Chinese web manhua by Ling Meng and Ming Xung.

The main character, Shu Yin, is **wearing a red scarf** in almost all scenes I have seen.

[image: Image of The Silver Guardian Manga]

In Chapter 2, Page 3 there is a scene where an older man is speaking to what appears to be a young Shu Yin and he says:

> So are you interested in **grandpa's new video game** idea?

And again in Chapter 5, Page 2 an elderly man appears out from a tomb and says:

> My dear grandchild
>
> Do you like what your **grandpa has prepared for you**?

More scenes from when Shu Yin was a child talking to his grandfather are from Chapter 8, Page 6 - 9, where his grandfather accidentally rips the scarf and offers feathers to Shu Yin for it to be mended.

And finally in Chapter 8, Page 12 there is a scene where Shu Yin's **scarf activates and he flies off**.

The description alludes to the fact he is the last Gravekeeper, and keeping the treasure safe from raiders:

> ...he expects to defeat the boss enemy to win, right? Alas, it turns out he's the **last Gravekeeper** and he's supposed to protect the treasure against the **Tomb Raiders**.

The summary has the following points:

- Shu Yin is a poor gamer whose consciousness goes to a virtual reality game without warning
- His quest is not fighting monsters, but to help them protect treasures from players called Tomb Raiders
- A story of a gamer's purpose to protect the tomb from raiders that want to use the power within it